# What is Julia Ordering?

Tags: sorting, julia

```
sort(v; alg::Algorithm=defalg(v), lt=isless, by=identity, rev::Bool=false, order::Ordering=Forward)
```

`order::Ordering=Forward` confuses me, I can not find any document about it.

- What is `Ordering`
- What is `Forward`

Comment: Can you link other code? They could be custom types. “::” means of type.

Comment: This signature of `sort` is from Julia official documentation, so they are not custom types. We can get it by `?sort` in REPL.

Comment: I found source code of them. <https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/ordering.jl> I wonder why there is no docs about them.

Comment: There is a new section in the docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.7-dev/base/sort/#Alternate-orderings

Answer (score 1):

These are defined in the module `Base.Order`:

```
help?> Base.Order.Ordering
      Base.Order.Ordering

  Abstract type which represents a total order on some set of elements.

  Use Base.Order.lt to compare two elements according to the ordering.

help?> Base.Order.Forward
  Base.Order.Forward

  Default ordering according to isless.
```

In order to find it out I just run:

```
@edit sort([1,2,3])
```

This is a very useful macro to find out what is going on.